# Conda wants to downgrade unrelated packages when uninstalling

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I used conda to install the galpy package as follows:

conda install galpy -c conda-forge

It installed and updated a number of packages along the way:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

```
blas:            1.0-mkl                          
galpy:           1.4.0-py27hb26f9ae_0  conda-forge
gsl:             2.2.1-h002c638_3                 
kiwisolver:      1.0.1-py27h2d50403_2  conda-forge
```

The following packages will be UPDATED:

```
ca-certificates: 2018.4.16-0           conda-forge --> 2018.10.15-ha4d7672_0 conda-forge
certifi:         2018.4.16-py27_0      conda-forge --> 2018.10.15-py27_1000  conda-forge
conda:           4.5.9-py27_0          conda-forge --> 4.5.11-py27_1000      conda-forge
matplotlib:      2.1.2-py27h6d6146d_0              --> 2.2.2-py27_1          conda-forge
numpy:           1.14.0-py27h8a80b8c_1             --> 1.14.2-py27ha9ae307_0            
openssl:         1.0.2o-h470a237_1     conda-forge --> 1.0.2p-h470a237_1     conda-forge
```

I then realized that instead of having a system-wide installation of galpy, I would rather just have a copy in my user space. So I tried to uninstall galpy using "conda uninstall galpy"... but it now wants to downgrade a bunch of unrelated packages, including python itself:

The following packages will be REMOVED:

```
galpy:           1.4.0-py27hb26f9ae_0    conda-forge
```

The following packages will be UPDATED:

```
cryptography:    2.1.4-py27hdbc5e8f_0                --> 2.4.1-py27ha12b0ac_0
curl:            7.58.0-ha441bb4_0                   --> 7.62.0-ha441bb4_0   
libcurl:         7.58.0-hf30b1f0_0                   --> 7.62.0-h051b688_0   
libssh2:         1.8.0-h322a93b_4                    --> 1.8.0-ha12b0ac_4    
openssl:         1.0.2p-h470a237_1       conda-forge --> 1.1.1-h1de35cc_0
```

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

```
ca-certificates: 2018.10.15-ha4d7672_0   conda-forge --> 2018.03.07-0        
certifi:         2018.10.15-py27_1000    conda-forge --> 2018.10.15-py27_0   
conda:           4.5.11-py27_1000        conda-forge --> 4.5.11-py27_0       
pycurl:          7.43.0.1-py27hdbc3d79_0             --> 7.19.0-py27_1       
python:          2.7.14-hde5916a_29                  --> 2.7.3-5             
readline:        7.0-hc1231fa_4                      --> 6.2-2
```

1. Why does it want to downgrade these packages that it never touched in the first place? I have done absolutely no package management in between the install and the uninstall.
2. Is it safe to use --force to uninstall? The documentation gives dire warnings, but I have literally not done anything else in between and nothing depends on galpy, so it feels like it ought to be safe. If not, what can I do to avoid these downgrades?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling using a command specifying the channel as well? `conda uninstall galpy -c conda-forge`

Comment: Yes, that works! Can you post this as a solution so I can upvote it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have to specify the same channel that you were using when installing. In this case:

```
conda uninstall galpy -c conda-forge
```